# MDM is Not Saving Session Data .dmrc file

Tags: gdm, mdm

Am trying to replace LightDM with MDM in 13.10. Am able to install and configure MDM, but when I go to login the system tells me that the .dmrc file is being ignored. Initially there was no .dmrc file, but I copied one from another user. I moved that to my home directory and changed the permissions to 644. This didn't solve the problem. I can confirm that my user owns $HOME; however, in the "Other" section of the folder properties it says others can read/write.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too quick on the draw. Solved this problem by changing home folder permissions to exclude Reading or viewing by others.